# Alternative to Perl's <> in Raku?

Tags: migration, raku

Here learning my way around Raku (neé Perl 6), very nice all around. But I sorely miss the magic `<>` from Perl 5, where you can just:

```
my $x = <>;
print $x;
while(<>) {
  print join(':', split);
}
```

(read next input line into `$x`, loop over the rest; input is from the files named as input or standard input if no file given). The "Perl 5 to 6" tutorials/migration guides/... just talk about `slurp`ing the whole file, or `open`ing individual files by name. No magic "take input from named files in sequence" I can find.

I want the magic back!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for largely exists. This script:

```
my $x = get();
say "First: $x";
for lines() {
    .say
}
```

Given these inputs files:

```
$ cat foo
foo line 1
foo line 2
$ cat bar
bar line 1
bar line 2
```

Will, when invoked as:

```
raku script.p6 foo bar
```

Produce the output:

```
First: foo line 1
foo line 2
bar line 1
bar line 2
```

It will also take output from `$*IN` if there aren't files. The only thing that doesn't exist is a single replacement for `<>`, since that would depend on `wantarray`-like functionality, which is incompatible with multiple dispatch (and Raku considers multiple dispatch is far more useful).

The zero-arg candidates for `get` and `lines` are implemented [in terms of `$*ARGFILES`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::ArgFiles), a file handle that provides the functionality of taking the files from the argument list or from `$*IN` - meaning one can pass it to any code that expects a file handle.

Comment: or, pedantically: raku script.raku foo bar. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Enough magic for you?

```
sub MAIN( Str $file where *.IO.f  )
{
    .say for $file.IO.lines.map: *.comb.join(':');
}
```

Comment: That's cool, and OP should try it, but it's not the same in a few ways. See jnthn's answer for how to emulate `<>`'s behavior, and note that raku's `.comb` without an argument splits a string into individual characters, whereas Perl's `split` without an argument is, afaik, `.split(/\s+/)` in raku.

Comment: An alternative to `.split` would be `.words` – https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str#routine_words

Comment: Why, by the holy rngesus, do i keep forgetting about the `words` method?